# Count array values in a loop and then add together

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with this for a while now and getting more important at the moment.

Lets say we have a array with the values

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 7
)
```

when i loop this array in a foreach loop i want the first result 11 second result 36 (11 + 25) 3rd result 38 (11 + 25 + 2) 4rd result 45 (11 + 25 + 2 +7) etc....
this way i get cumulative results

This is what i tried so far:

```
<?php
                                            foreach(array_slice(weeks($start_week), 0, 26) as $week):
                                                $gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten_cumulatief"][$week] = $gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten"][$row["kenmerk"]][$week] + $gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten"][$row["kenmerk"]][$week-1];

                                                $gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten_cumulatief"][$week] += $gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten"][$row["kenmerk"]][$week];

endforeach;

foreach(array_slice(weeks($start_week), 0, 26) as $week):
                                                echo "<td week='".$week."' class='part1'>".$gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten_cumulatief"][$week]."</td>";

endforeach;                                                                 
                                            foreach(array_slice(weeks($start_week), 26, 51) as $week):
                                                echo "<td week='".$week."' class='part2'>".$gewasregistratie["gezette_vruchten_cumulatief"][$week]."</td>";
endforeach;

?>
```

Can someone help me in the right direction ?

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Please use short placeholders for variables, and minimize indentation for readability.

Answer (score 3):

Simple like boiling a egg. Try this code

```
$test  = array(11,25,2,7);
$count = 0;
foreach($test as $i=>$k)
{
    $count +=$k;
    echo $count."   ";
}
```

Output:

```
11 36 38 45
```

**Suggestion:** you can store output in another array also.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$a = array(11,25,2,7);

$c = 0;
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $c += $v;
    $b[] = $c;
}
print_r($b);
```

you will get result in array like below :

Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 36 [2] => 38 [3] => 45 )

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way

```
$original = array(23, 18, 5, 8, 10, 16);

$total = array();
$runningSum = 0;

foreach ($original as $number) {
    $runningSum += $number;
    $total[] = $runningSum;
}

var_dump($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array( 11, 25, 2, 7 );
$results = array();

foreach ($array AS $i => $v) {
  if (empty($results)) {
    $results[] = $v;
  } else {
    $results[] = $v + $results[$i - 1];
  }
}
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$arr=Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 7
);
$sum=0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$val)
{
   echo "<br>".$sum+=$val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below solution

```
$arr = array(11,25,2,7);
$sum =0;
foreach($arr as $val){
    $sum +=$val;    
echo $sum ."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to iterate over a single-dimensional array as your question was initially worded, `array_map` would be your most efficient method:

```
function cascade($n) {
    static $current = 0;
    return $current += (int) $n;
}

$test = array(11,25,2,7);

$result = array_map('cascade', $test);
/**
 * You could also assign back to the original array like:
 * $test = array_map('cascade', $test);
 */
```

If you are looking to do something in a multi-dimensional array, using `array_walk` would be the solution there.  Would you like an example?

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
$myArray = Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 7
);

$total = 0;

for($i=1; $i <= count($myArray); $i++) {
   $total += $myArray[$i];

   echo $total . ", ";

   $cumulativeArray[] = $total;
}

print_r($cumulativeArray);
```

Comment: It is not what the OP asked.

Comment: @ThomasRuiz : It's related to user needs only.